# Who is author/designer/creator of PBKDF2 algorithm?

Tags: hash, pbkdf2

Just consisting list of credits/references who's algorithms I've used in my software and found that I couldn't identify who is real author of [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)

Can anyone hint me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PBKDF2 (RFC 2898) was developed by RSA Laboratories as part of the PKCS series of standards.  While there has been no public recognition of the individuals who worked on this specific algorithm as far as I know, Burt Kaliski was the Chief Scientist and Editor of the PKCS at the time, (and author of RFC 2898) so its fair to give him some measure of credit for it.

Answer (score 1):

The first draft of PBKDF2 was submitted on may 1999 by Burt Kaliski on working RSA Lab under the company name Security Dynamic that acquired RSA Data Security in 1996 then in 1999 RSA Data Security and Security Dynamic joint product line under the RSA name.

here is the Document history

```
2000-09-01  RFC     (System)    RFC published
2000-06-15  04      (System)    IESG has approved the document
2000-06-05  04      (System)    New version available: draft-kaliski-pkcs5-v2-04.txt (diff from previous)
2000-02-22  03      (System)    New version available: draft-kaliski-pkcs5-v2-03.txt (diff from previous)
1999-11-29  02      (System)    New version available: draft-kaliski-pkcs5-v2-02.txt (diff from previous)
1999-07-12  01      (System)    New version available: draft-kaliski-pkcs5-v2-01.txt (diff from previous)
1999-05-26  00      (System)    New version available: draft-kaliski-pkcs5-v2-00.txt
```

So, his the man.